# Funcion para verificar que una cadena tenga solo letras c# consola

Tags: c#

Bien, chicos estoy haciendo un programa en consola, con funciones, el programa trata de una factura el cual debes ingresar el nombre de una persona(nombre del producto, cantidad, precio ect..) y calcular el subtotal y total. Pero como estamos trabajando con funciones, debo realizar una funcion la cual permita verificar cuando el usuario ingrese su nombre, este solo contenga letras y no numeros ni carecteres especiales, de lo contrario, dar un mensaje de error, y dejar ingresar el mismo hasta que este correcto. Muchas gracias de ante mano cualquier ayuda me sera de mucha ayuda, estoy algo perdido (sí, soy principiante).

Comment: Hola para poder ayudarte tienes que compartir tú código, mostrarnos donde te lanza error que has intentado. Te invito ha hacer un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y sobre cualquier duda puedes visitar esta [sección de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Suerte

Answer (score 3):

Dejo unos tres ejemplos de propuestas de verificar si es una cadena contiene solo letras
(ademas lo dejo en un [repositorio > verify-is-letter-or-digit-benchmark](https://github.com/fernandezja/verify-is-letter-or-digit-benchmark) para clon o fork).

Estos ejemplos utilizan

- **WithRegEx**: La expresion regular famosa de que si esta o no en el rango de A-Z o a-z
- **WithCharIsLetter** con el metodo de [char.IsLetter](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.char.isletter)
- **WithForCompareAsciiValue** recorriendo caracter por cararacter y verificando si el valor ascii del mismo es el que necesitamos

El codigo esta aqui

```
    public bool WithRegEx(string stringToVerify) {
        return Regex.IsMatch(stringToVerify, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    }

    public bool WithCharIsLetter(string stringToVerify)
    {
        return stringToVerify.All(char.IsLetter);
    }

    public bool WithForCompareAsciiValue(string stringToVerify)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stringToVerify.Length; i++)
        {
            //A=65 Z=90 and a=97 z=122
            if ((int)stringToVerify[i] < 65 || ((int)stringToVerify[i] > 90 
                && (int)stringToVerify[i] < 97) || (int)stringToVerify[i] > 122)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Si comparamos la ejecución de estos métodos (hice el repositorio porque arme un ejemplo y compare con [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet))

Los ejecute con el texto "la fuerza estara contigo siempre", el resultado...

```
                Method    |       Mean |      Error |     StdDev | Ratio | Allocated| 
               WithRegEx  | 468.929 ns | 18.4859 ns | 53.6309 ns |  1.00 |    104 B |
         WithCharIsLetter |  97.563 ns |  3.3264 ns |  9.4904 ns |  0.21 |     96 B |
 WithForCompareAsciiValue |   9.019 ns |  0.2194 ns |  0.4997 ns |  0.02 |        - |
```

Donde

- Mean: Tiempo promedio de todas las mediciones significativas.
- StdDev: desviación estándar de estas medidas
- Ratio: Es la variación con respecto a un método base (en este caso el WithRegEx)
- Allocated: Memoria asignada

Podemos ver que si quieres velocidad de ejecución con casi nula utilización de memoria, puedes ver el método simple de comparación por carácter ascii.
Pero si quieres algo simple ya tenemos RegEx que dentro de todo es simple (incluso si agregamos los acentos) y [char.IsLetter](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.char.isletter) (pero que no tiene la parte de acentos en español).

Si es solo para una app consola lo que necesitas, puedes decidir no por la performance sino por lo mas rápido para codificar y entender.

**A tener en cuenta!!** Es un ejemplo simple, hay agregar a este código de ejemplo la parte de acentos en nuestro querido idioma español

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guía:

- [Char.IsLetter](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.char.isletter)
- [Repositorio > verify-is-letter-or-digit-benchmark](https://github.com/fernandezja/verify-is-letter-or-digit-benchmark)

Answer (score 0):

Para sólo letras, usá esta función:

```
Regex.IsMatch(variable, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

Saludos!

Comment: Revisa por favor [answer], modifica tu respuesta ya que se reporto como de baja calidad.